# head command options and reading man files

Tags: man, head

I have two environments: Mac and Linux.

I wonder about the [head](/questions/tagged/head) command:

it can show just 2 lines of text if I invoke it like so:

```
vim --version | head -2
```

I saw this online and ran to the [man](/questions/tagged/man) page to learn more only to discover that neither the [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) nor the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) pages have any information that I could decipher describing the possibility of using `-2` directly to get *just 2 lines* of text from [stdin](/questions/tagged/stdin).

So my questions are:

- am I reading the man pages wrong?
- if so, what indicates the possibility of specifying `-2` directly?
- if not, is it common for recognised options not to be explicitly outlined in the [man](/questions/tagged/man) page?
- if not in [man](/questions/tagged/man), where should I look for *full disclosure* on a command's options?
- are there many other *convenient* features like this, which objectively make [head](/questions/tagged/head) much nicer and direct to use, that I am oblivious to and can't learn about by studying `-h` output and/or a [man](/questions/tagged/man) page?

---

#### Mac

[osx](/questions/tagged/osx) **OS X v10.8.3 (build 12D78)**

---

#### Linux

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) **GNU/Linux (kernel 3.5.0-25-generic) Ubuntu 12.10**

[coreutils](/questions/tagged/coreutils) **GNU coreutils 8.12.197-032bb**

---

Comment: Hiya, am not sure I'm understanding your question clearly.  If you have ten lines of stdin text and pipe it to head i.e. # cat somefile.txt | head -n 2     It should spit out the first two lines of somefile.txt (btw, -2 may work, but -n is the actual argument to specify the number of lines, while -c specifies the number of bytes.)

Comment: `head -2` is synonym to `head -n 2`, why? Where does it say so in the manual? `head -3` is synonym to `head -n 3`, etc. This being the case but not being explicitly documented has a feel of "black magic"/"secret lore".. ;)

Comment: At least you'll get the full disclosure by reading the source, Luke.

Comment: And by doing so, succumb to the hopelessness of the dev/user divide, plunging into a life of pessimism and psycho-active tablets. There must be hope beyond browsing the source!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you've found the backwards compatibility flags (which, to be honest, I had never known existed.)

From the man page:

```
SEE ALSO
       The  full documentation for head is maintained as a Texinfo manual.  If the info and head programs
       are properly installed at your site, the command

              info coreutils 'head invocation'
```

At the bottom of the info coreutils page:

```
For compatibility `head' also supports an obsolete option syntax
`-COUNTOPTIONS', which is recognized only if it is specified first.
COUNT is a decimal number optionally followed by a size letter (`b',
`k', `m') as in `-c', or `l' to mean count by lines, or other option
letters (`cqv').  Scripts intended for standard hosts should use `-c
COUNT' or `-n COUNT' instead.  If your script must also run on hosts
that support only the obsolete syntax, it is usually simpler to avoid
`head', e.g., by using `sed 5q' instead of `head -5'.

An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value indicates failure.
```

Comment: So the answer to one of the points above is: sometimes look into the `info` of the command after reading the `--help` and `man`..

Comment: yep; especially if the bottom of the man page suggests it ;)

Comment: I guess another point to learn is: some options fall out of fashion, get deprecated and are actively hidden/deprecated so that new users (like me) will avoid them. You know what I think would be _better_ than this _hiding_ (not putting in plain sight) approach? Just show the option and _say_: don't use this - it may not be there in a future version. I would have been less confused. Probably just me though.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, you also taught me some more in the process, I appreciate it.